# New error in VS 2019, but there is no error? C++

Tags: error-handling, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I have been working on  a project for a while now, with many stable builds sent out etc.
Today however, I encountered 3 errors in one line of code (in a page of code that is only 17 lines long), that has been working perfectly fine for over a year now.
I'll show the "broken code" below.
The only problem is, there is no error. No red underlines or any actual problem, nothing has been changed, or anything I can think of. I made one minor edit today to the project that was entirely unrelated to that specific code, apart from calling one of two functions inside of it. The called function isn't even the function that is breaking.
Worst of all, a project backup that is almost identical compiles no problems. Again, it's only that 1 minor edit unrelated that is different.
Visual studio error list shows me three errors;
Error   C3083   'chrono': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
Error   C2039   'time_point': is not a member of 'std'
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'time_point'

Here is the offending code.

```
#ifndef _INPUT_HPP
#define _INPUT_HPP

#include "../Structure/Struct.hpp"

namespace Input
{
    bool IsPressed(int virtual_key);

    namespace Mouse
    {
        void Lerp(Vector2 pos, double animation, double repeat_delay, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> f_excess);
    }
}


#endif
```

All errors come from line 12 - starting with: void lerp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't `#include <chrono>`, so of course the compiler does not know the symbols.

You might have been including it indirectly and stopped because you removed some other `#include` directive somewhere else. Don't rely on indirect `#include`s—you are using it here, you should have `#include <chrono>` here. See [include-what-you-use](https://include-what-you-use.org/).

Comment: Cheers mate, I was quite tired when I wrote that post and should have realised from the errors presented!